# Why is there no server.emit in this code and i am having trouble understanding this code in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble understanding this code.

1. My confusion is on line 8 (server.on) . After we use server.on it will listen for an event but why is there server.emit not being used? And what is doing the work of server.emit
2. Is it compulsory to write emit after on or not?

Please help me understand this code too.

Thank You. The code is below

```
const http = require('http');
const PORT = 8000;

// Using Event Emmiter API
const server = http.createServer();
// emits request event
// subscribe to it / listen for it / respond to it
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  res.end(`Welcome`);
});

server.listen(PORT);
```

[image: I am having confusion from line 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an http server.  One of the events you can listen for on an http server is the `request` event that indicates there's an incoming http request.  You can see all the events that the http server object supports [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserver).

This particular event provides two arguments - the `req` and `res` objects.  To send a response back to the client, you use the response object `res`.  You can use `res.write()` and/or `res.end()`.  This particular example uses `res.end('Welcome')` to send a simple text response back to the client.

There is no `.emit()` because that's not how the http server object works.  Internally, it uses `.emit()` to create events that listeners can get notified about, but when you are listening for an event, you don't use `.emit()` yourself.  Instead, you use the data that comes with the event to act appropriately for that particular event.  In this case, you use the request and response objects which are sent with the `request` event.

> . After we use server.on it will listen for an event but why is there server.emit not being used?

The server itself is using `server.emit()` internally to trigger events that you can listen to.

> And what is doing the work of server.emit

It's not clear what you're expecting here.  `.emit()` is a method on an `eventEmitter` object and it is called to trigger events that other code can listen for.  The http server object uses it internally to trigger events, but sending an http response has nothing at all to do with the eventEmitter object or `.emit()`.  Instead, you use methods on the response object to send an http response back to the client.

> Is it compulsory to write emit after on or not?

No.  You would not usually use `.emit()` in a `.on()` listener.  But, it really depends upon what the event is and how to code that triggered the event is written.  You could theoretically call `.emit()` and trigger other events in response to an incoming event, but that's not required and is not usually how things are done.  For example, if you were listening for keyboard events or mouse click events, you would just act on those events (doing whatever you wanted based on the incoming keyboard or mouse click events) and not use `.emit()` to trigger more events.

---

If you are familiar with the socket.io library, it is one library that sends responses back to the client with `.emit()`.  So you would listen for an incoming message with `socket.on(...)` and send a response back to the client with `socket.emit(...)`.  But that is not a usual design and is not how the http server object works.  In this case the socket.io library has overriden the `.emit()` to do something different than it normally does with a standard `EventEmitter` object.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation on how the emit works as well.